# Como utilizar Request customizado em Controller

Tags: laravel

Segue meu `AuthRequest.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Rules\CpfValidacao;

class AuthRequest extends Request
{

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email'    => 'required|min:1|max:255',
            'cpf'      => ['required', 'min:1', 'max:11', new CpfValidacao],
            'name'     => 'required|min:1|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255'
            //'profile_picture_path' => 'required|min:1|max:255'
        ];
    }

    /*** Novas mensagens ***/
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
                'email.required'    => 'Campo email requerido!',
                'email.min'        => 'Campo email deve ser de no mínimo 1 caracter!',
                'email.max'        => 'Campo email deve ser de no máximo 255 caracteres!',
                'cpf.required'      => 'Campo cpf requerido!',
                'email.min'        => 'Campo cpf deve ser de no mínimo 1 dígito!',
                'email.max'        => 'Campo cpf deve ser de no máximo 11 dígitos!',
                'name.required'     => 'Campo name requerido!',
                'name.min'         => 'Campo name deve ser de no mínimo 1 caracter!',
                'name.max'         => 'Campo name deve ser de no máximo 255 caracteres!',
                'password.required' => 'Campo password requerido!',
                'password.min'     => 'Campo password deve ser de no mínimo 8 caracteres!',
                'password.max'     => 'Campo password deve ser de no máximo 255 caracteres!',
        ];
    }



}
```

Minha dúvida está aqui:

```
/*** Registra usuário ***/
    public function register(AuthRequest $request)
    {

        /*** validação de parâmetros ***/
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email'    => 'required|min:1|max:255',
            'cpf'      => ['required', 'min:1', 'max:11', new CpfValidacao],
            'name'     => 'required|min:1|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255'
            //'profile_picture_path' => 'required|min:1|max:255'
        ]);


        if($validator->fails()){
            $errors = $validator->erros();
            return response()->json(['error' => true, $errors], 422);
        }
        /*** fim ***/
```

Como faço a nova implementação?

`laravel 6.2`

Comment: Pergunta não diz o que você quer?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você quer usar o AuthRegisterRequest.php para validar a criação do usuário?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pergunta não ficou muito clara, se não for isso o que você está procurando edita a pergunta, ok?
Pelo que eu entendi você quer validar o usuário seguindo as regras do `AuthRegisterRequest.php`. Sendo assim, inclua o arquivo de request

```
use App\Http\Requests\AuthRegisterRequest;
```

Coloque o parâmetro da função que você quer validar como `AuthRegisterRequest`:

```
public function register(AuthRegisterRequest $request){}
```

E chame dentro da função `register` o método de validação:

```
public function register(AuthRegisterRequest $request)
   {
        $validated = $request->validated();
   }
```

Porém, se não for necessário trabalhar com os dados validados em sí dentro do controller, ou seja, se você quer apenas retornar o erro caso haja algum problema de validação, você pode abstrair esse código anterior no Controller e criar um método dentro do `AuthRegisterRequest.php` para fazer isso sempre. Dessa forma:

```
public function validation(Request $request, AuthRegisterRequest $Object)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $Object->rules(), [], $Object->names());

    if ($validator->fails())
        return $validator->errors();
    return true;
}
```

Com isso, nada das suas regras de validação precisará ser escrito no controller.

Comment: isso, minha ideia é tirar essa parte do `validator` do controller, utilizando um arquivo externo

Comment: aparentemente após a alteração que fiz, `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $Object->rules(),  $Object->messages());`, ainda não funciona a questão das mensagens, ainda aparecem em inglês

Comment: você verificou a importação do AuthRegisterRequest.php no controller?

Comment: Uma pequena alteração antes: Renomeei `AuthRegisterRequest` para `AuthRequest`. Fiz a importação da seguinte forma: `use App\Http\Requests\AuthRequest;`. `laravel 6.2`